# How to add a Wav file to Windows Form Application in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I was publishing my first C# Windows Form Application with a built-in audio player (I used System.Media), but when I tried to run the program on another PC of mine, it returned an exception and then crashed every time I click on the button to play audio so I was wondering if there was a way to play the audio on another PC without crashing.

Here's the code part I used to play the sound:

```
System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer("mouse_click.wav");
player.Play();
```

Then the PC I used to run the program returned this error: verify that the audio file path is correct.

Thank you everyone for the help!

Comment: *Verify that the audio file path is correct.*  In this particular case, the path you provided `("mouse_click.wav")` is most likely the same one that your executable is running in.

Comment: I have put the wav file in the same path as where the executable file is, so idk where could be the problem.

Comment: If the error says the file isn't there then it isn't there. How are you ensuring the file is deployed to the other computers?

Comment: I have no idea, I set up the wev file as Embedded Source and it's still not working, I don't know what to do I think I tried everything

Comment: Embedded resources need to be read out of the assembly because they are "embedded" into it, they are not copied to the folder. Use build action None, Copy to output

Comment: I'll try and let you know

Comment: I should mention you don't have to set build action to none and copy to output folder. Embedding the resource is perfectly valid, it just [does not do what you think it does.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.resources.resourcemanager.getstream?view=net-6.0)

Comment: Nope, not working: build action none, copy to output directory, copy always is that correct?

Comment: "Copy Always" is generally fine. When you build, do you see the file in the output folder?

Comment: No, there is any wav file In the folder, should I put it in the Application_files fonder to make it work?

Comment: It shouldn't matter where you put it, as long as it exists and your code is looking in the right place.

Comment: So how can I make the code to run on other PCs, I found no way to do that

Comment: It is not complicated, there must be something simple that you are missing. I cannot tell what that is without seeing more details about your solution and projects. I think if you [research build actions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/build-actions?view=vs-2022) you might find the problem.

Comment: Just tried moving the program folder to C:/ and then publishing it again, still not working. Any other ways?

Comment: You are using the word "publish". What is that exactly? Click-Once deployment? MSIX? Maybe the problem is with publishing. If you just build your solution (F6) and you look in the output folder can you find the wav file?

Comment: Problem solved guys, looking on some tutorials I realized that to make it work I had to put the file in the resource file and also set his persistence to "embedded to ".resx". Thank you al for the help!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add a Wav file to Windows Form Application, you can refer to the following steps:

First, add the Wav file in the Resources File (Project>Properties>Resources):
[image]

Second, refer to the following code to play the Wav file in VS:

```
System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(Properties.Resources._15035);//Use your own filename in place of _15035
player.Play();
```

Comment: May I know whether your issue have been solved or not? if not, please share it in here, we can work together to figure it out. If it can solve your problem, you can click '✔' to mark my reply as the accepted answer. It will also help others to solve the similar issue.